# disable sql-mode autocompletion in emacs

Tags: emacs, sql-mode

I'm trying to write my pl/sql code in following way: `id_sel` then hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> and I've got `id_select` completion! It works with any `...sel` word. I think it is an `sql-mode` feature. How to disable this?

Comment: I don't believe that's a `sql-mode` feature, and while it's common for people to have completion functionality on `TAB`, it seems a little unusual for it to be happening on `Enter`. What are those keys actually bound to?

Comment: Just to support @phils, while in the sql-mode try C-h k and <TAB> see what it bounds to. The only completion for sql-mode in mine is YASnippet that uses TabKey2 to complete.

Comment: `(newline &optional ARG)` for `Enter` and `(self-insert-command N)` for `TAB`

Answer (score 1):

It's all about `abbrev-mode`.
`abbrev-mode` by default uses `.abbrev_defs` file, that utilizes `sql-mode-abbrev-table` variable from `sql-mode.sql`.